# Question about recovery log

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery

i got a brand new nokia phone a few days ago. The phone and box was in new condition except a tiny bit of dirt/gunk on one of the metal rim/side of the phone.

This got me thinking as to whether the phone might be refurbished, so i took a look at the recovery menu and noticed that the View recovery logs already had a log inside it. The first line says, 'Started recovery on Tue 27 Jan....' I am guessing the date is the default 27 Jan 1970 a lot of folders on the phone have currently.

My question is: Are brand new phones supposed to have this recovery log file, or is this an indication that the phone is refurbished?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

The recovery should essentially have logs. The factory also tests the device sensors and hardware for normal functionality. So, I'm guessing one of those tests would also be about checking that recovery mode is accessible or not.

You should check for warranty in the Nokia Support app and I wouldn't worry if it shows the device in warranty.